# git clone trailing slash

Tags: git, github

I would just like to understand the significance of a trailing slash with `git clone`, especially as only the one without a trailing slash seems to work (for a colleague both seem fine).

```
$ git clone https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/
Cloning into 'examples'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

$ git clone https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples
Cloning into 'examples'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 979, done.
remote: Total 979 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 979
Receiving objects: 100% (979/979), 326.45 KiB | 2.61 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (330/330), done.

$ git --version
git version 2.21.0
```

Comment: Could you run the first command with `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and include the output in an edit to your post?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior: `git clone` behaves the same with either URL (git version 2.20.1 and 2.21.0).

Comment: I wrote up an answer based on observations from the past, but tried your example both ways (and also with `example.git`) and all worked for me, suggesting that GitHub have made this work for multiple different cases now. So I deleted that answer...

Comment: bk2204 No additional output by increasing GIT_CURL_VERBOSE 

larsks: I could also not reproduce that on a colleagues machine which makes it even weirder...

Comment: One more piece `git clone https://username@github.com/bazelbuild/examples/` also works

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured out the issue I had added 
`git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"` to my gitconfig a while back...